# Is it possible to debug Apache AGE's make installcheck?

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

I am developing for [Apache AGE](https://github.com/apache/age) and I use the command `make installcheck` a lot to test the things I just did.

I was wondering if there's a way to debug this command under GDB or any other tool, and set breakpoints where I want. That would make my life much easier.

I tried `gdb --args make installcheck` but it didn't seem to work.

---

## Edit:

I already know how to use GDB, what I want to know is if I can debug the tests that are made when I give the command `make installcheck` on the root of Apache AGE directory.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to debug the extension. First you want to start the postgres server (which i assume you know that already) and then use the following command `ps aux | grep postgres`.

Find the process that says postgres: idle, then use the number in the second column here: `sudo gdb -p <insert number here>` and you are done! You may want to read more about the `gdb` debugger like setting breakpoints, examining values etc. so you can be more comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

I believe with the `make` command there isn't, but one way you could do it is to, as other said, have an instance of postgres running, get the backend pid, attach it to gdb, then set a breakpoint to the function that the regression test is calling and then execute the same queries from the regression tests.

You can also read the `regression/regression.diffs` to see what are the changes between the tests and also the output files.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you could use GDB or read the `regression.diffs` file. Another thing you could do is to read the tests themselves. They're located in the regress/ folder. The way they are organized is that inside regress/ there are two folders: one is called sql and one is called expected. If you inspect them you'll notice that the files within them have mirrored names. This is because the files in expected/ contain the results of the queries in sql/, or what the queries should be if the tests passed. To debug make installcheck, you
could try adding your own queries inside one of the sql files and the expected result inside one of the .out files. The command `make installcheck` will check if they both match.

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach gdb to with postgresql to carry out this task:

1. Start the age with debugging symbols.

> ./configure --enable-debug
> make

2. Initiate the postgreSQL Server with gdb debugger.

> gdb --args postgres -D /path/to/data/directory -p

3. Put the breakpoints and start running the tests.

> break my_function

Start debugging the tests.

Answer (score 0):

In order to debug Apache AGE's make installcheck,  you can follow these steps:

- Compiling the AGE with debug symbols like `-g` flag and start GDB using `gdb` command alone.
- After starting GDB, you need to attach gdb to the `make installcheck` process with the process id of `make installcheck`. The command for attaching gdb will be:

```
attach PID
```

- After this, you can use keywords like  `break` and `continue` for debugging by setting breakpoints.